Amazon ECR "Layer already exists", is there a way to force ECR to update?
New images with the same tag won't push to ECR. Initial push of image to ECR seems to work, but if I'm attempting to create a subsequent build I get "Layer already exists" and nothing changes even though my local docker cache has updated.
I have the --nocache option enabled on the docker build:
docker build --no-cache --target eks -t ${aws_account_id}.dkr.ecr.${aws_region}.amazonaws.com/${ecr_repo}:${build_tag}

The build on my build server contains updated code.
docker push ${aws_account_id}.dkr.ecr.${aws_region}.amazonaws.com/${ecr_repo}:${build_tag}

results in:
5f70bf18a086: Layer already exists
29f76733b608: Layer already exists
39dc6106a950: Layer already exists
c2e8b623318e: Layer already exists
2aeae0baeff6: Layer already exists
b90b75df0e47: Layer already exists
1e62d68319d5: Layer already exists
e96ceb5f9545: Layer already exists
deafb97bd25e: Layer already exists
af7a2ab75583: Layer already exists
150fc640e164: Layer already exists
89442d8a6d4e: Layer already exists
ecd0c1bc8d94: Layer already exists
c37a8863d35e: Layer already exists
7f0175a09165: Layer already exists
9ea571566ff7: Layer already exists
8d6551b23d41: Layer already exists
8badcfdd9076: Layer already exists

Even though it says that, the code in ECR is not updated, subsequent rebuilds with the same tag have the same issue. New tags don't seem to matter, deleting the image from ECR doesn't matter, same issue. Only thing that fixes it is moving to an entirely new ECR, but then subsequent rebuilds experience the same issue. This all worked fine for weeks, but suddenly started doing this.
If I run the docker container on the build server using:
docker run -it <image id> bash

I can see it is up to date, but when that tagged image is pushed to ECR, an older revision is pulled, doesn't contain the most recent docker push.
This thread is basically the same problem, no answer from Amazon on it: https://repost.aws/questions/QUwkv1zCjuQHOvTmzPgVqEVg/ecr-is-not-deleting-images-how-to-force-layer-upload
Any hints are greatly appreciated.

This is an XY Problem. Please show how the image should have changed, exact steps to build and push it, and the exact steps to pull it and see the unchanged image. See [mcve] for more details.

The "layer already exists" message indicates that the MD5 hash of the layers has not changed. That's not a bug in ECR. It sounds like the actual issue you are encountering is that the deployment is not using newer images that you push to ECR. First, I would download the latest image from ECR back to your local computer, and run it or otherwise examine it to make sure it actually has your latest changes in it. If it doesn't, then you need to look into your build process. If it does then you need to look into your deployment process. We would need more details in order to help you further.

Thanks for the tips all, I ended up giving up on this, it only seems to be a problem when reusing tags. I've read other stack overflows that show it's just generally not a good idea to do it. Would be nice to fix this, but the solution for me was to always push a unique tag. Re-using tags seems to be buggy and sometimes it's impossible to fully purge the old tag if you are trying to push another with the same name.

@BMitch I can run the container from my local docker cache built using command above, it contains the most recent code, however when I push to ECR (layer already exists message) and pull it back down the code is a previous version.
docker run -i -t 8dbd9e392a96 /bin/bash

Always use unique tags, reusing tags is problematic. Consider turning on tag immutability to avoid this issue entirely.
